# Firebase Security Rules -- using attribute from User document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm struggling to make my Firebase security rules work.
I only want to allow write access to documents in the collection `Nouns` to users with the attribute `'admin' == true` (boolean) in their user document (stored in collection `Users`).

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    
    match /Users/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null 
                && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
    
    match /Nouns/{documents=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null 
    }
    
    match /Nouns/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null 
                && resource.data.admin == true
    }
    
    
  }
}
```

The rules playground gives the following error when I try a write on a document in the `Nouns` collection:

> Error: simulator.rules line [17], column [13]. Property admin is undefined on object.

Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resource.data` will contain data of the document being accessed in Nouns collection. If you want to read data from user's document, use `get()` instead:

```
match /Nouns/{documents=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null 
                && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
}
```

Collection names are case-sensitive so make sure you enter it correctly.